# inadequate results using tensorflow,

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction, volatile

I am currently trying to get more into ML using tensorflow. My current project is predicting the prices for the s&p500 for the next 10 days. I already have the following code but the problem is, that the results are more or less inadequate meaning that they are extremely volatile and even go below zero. Is there a mistake i have overlooked?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

file_path = "gspc.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

data = df.filter(["Close"])
dataset = data.values
training_data_len = math.ceil(len(dataset) * 0.8)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

train_data = scaled_data[0:training_data_len, :]
x_train = []
y_train = []

for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i - 60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=50)

test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - 60:, :]
x_test = []
y_test = dataset[training_data_len:, :]
for i in range(60, len(test_data)):
    x_test.append(test_data[i-60:i, 0])

x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))

predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(predictions - y_test)**2)

train = data[:training_data_len]
valid = data[training_data_len:]
valid["Predictions"] = predictions

last_60_days = data[-60:].values
last_60_days_scaled = scaler.transform(last_60_days)

prediction_list = []

for i in range(10):
    x_input = last_60_days_scaled.reshape((1, 60, 1))

    next_price = model.predict(x_input)[0, 0]

    prediction_list.append(next_price)
    last_60_days = np.append(last_60_days[1:], [[next_price]], axis=0)
    last_60_days_scaled = scaler.transform(last_60_days)

prediction_list = scaler.inverse_transform(np.array(prediction_list).reshape(-1, 1))

print(prediction_list)
```

i tried it with using more epochs. But the result is still not satisfactory

Comment: What else have you tried to diagnose the issue (other than adding more epochs)? What were your findings?

Comment: Also, you should post your input. Is it [this](https://github.com/llSourcell/Reinforcement_Learning_for_Stock_Prediction/blob/master/data/%5EGSPC.csv)?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to predict stock prices by assuming there are fixed patterns in how the valuation goes up and down. This is a flawed assumption to make. The stock market is notoriously difficult to predict, especially in this algorithmic trading age, where these predictions are already baked into the valuation. It makes it even more difficult when the model's only input is the price in the previous days.

That being said, it may be easier to try using historical data from the early 1900s, if you can find it. Then you could see if your model can find any consistent patterns in a time period when the market *might* (I'm no expert on this) have had more predictable patterns in how the price goes up and down. As I mentioned though, only using the previous days' price as the input really makes it tough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i already tried to extend the given stock prices and made some adjustment on the model. I just wanted to make sure that the code is more or less correct and it is realistic for the program that the prices are decreasing so much in just 10 days.

Comment: @FaBrown I'm not sure. Consider adding comments to your code to clarify what's going on. I would also suggest breaking it down into functions (maybe like `prepare_data(stock_data)`, `create_model(input_shape)`, etc. to improve readability. Specifying your input (e.g., a link to the gspc.csv file on a github gist) would be helpful as well.

Comment: @FaBrown I am curious, did you write this code personally or get it from somewhere? It is difficult to help without more details on the specific issue and what steps you've taken to try and figure it out.

Comment: @FaBrown My purpose in asking if you wrote it is to see if it would be reasonable to ask you for more details, like how you chose your method of normalizing the data, loss function, the time window for your input, model layers, etc.